# 'scomp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a .jar file from .xsd files  by using windows batch file.
In that batch file i provided java and xmlbeans path java version1.4.2 and xmlbeans version is 2.4.0

The tried this code on other system but getting same error.

```
set XMLBEANS_HOME=D:\newBatchJars\jXBeanGenerator\xmlbeans-2.4.0
set JAVA_HOME=D:\newBatchJars\jXBeanGenerator\j2sdk1.4.2\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%;

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%XMLBEANS_HOME%\lib\xbean.jar;%XMLBEANS_HOME%\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;

scomp -out jXBeanBatches.jar -compiler %JAVA_HOME%   *.xsd

pause
```

I want a jar ("jXBeanBatches.jar") which will be generated after executing the batch file.
The out is a error  "'scomp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `XMLBEANS_HOME=D:\newBatchJars\jXBeanGenerator\xmlbeans-2.4.0` to `XMLBEANS_HOME=D:\newBatchJars\jXBeanGenerator\xmlbeans-2.4.0\bin`